# django forms blank label

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to use django forms, and I am interested in rending a form with " blank label".

Something like:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
     q = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs {'id':'field','name':'field'}),label="Search")
```

and then I render the form in my html using

```
{{form.as_p}}
```

However, I have this annoying "Search:" being displayed on my html, which I dont want. I have tried using just:

```
q = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs {'id':'field','name':'field'}))
```

but this outputs "Q:", which I guess is the default label. How do I tell django that I do not need the label rendered?

Many thanks.

Comment: OK I have found out the answer. Better to pass name "q" directly in html <input> field as name.

Comment: You can also render form field by field, ommiting label tag.

Comment: what do you mean szaman? For example, I used: <input id="field" name="q" type="text" />. What would be nicer is to use django specific code: something like {{form.q}} instead of name="q" and I was wondering if this is possible. I tried {{form.q}},{{form.data.q}} etc but none of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example, it should clarify how to use it: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Are you sure {{ form.q }} does not work?

Comment: Szaman.. Yea I have looked at the docs. For some reason {{form.q}} does not work. Worth mentioning that this form is actually in haystack. So when I call it "q" seems to work but {{form.q}} does not work. Strange.

Comment: Szaman, actually, {{form.q}} now does work. I had to reload all modules. But, for example, I dont like the style of {{form.q}} input box, and have my own input box, something like: <input id="field" name="q" type="text"/>. Here, I use name=q and everything works as expected. If I use name="{{forms.q}}" it dosent work. Is using name=q in such situations normal? Thanks.

Comment: What is the difference between manually typed input tag by you and this one rendered by django using form.q? You can adjust every form field to your needs and don`t have to type input tag manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
     q = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs {'id':'field','name':'field'}),label="")
```

That will just set the label to the empty string.